# SSH Host Based Authentication Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I am trying to configure Host Based Authentication for SSH from Windows to Windows using OpenSSH. I have found the following articles but they are Linux based.

```
https://www.golinuxcloud.com/configure-ssh-host-based-authentication-linux/
https://www.lehigh.edu/~insna/OpenSSH-HOWTO-hostbased-auth.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E37125/sshuser-12.html
```

I have followed the same steps as mentioned in these articles. Although I know that the configurations should be same, but somehow I am not able to connect to remote machine. Here is the error I am getting

**Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive,hostbased)**

I am not able to understand what I am missing. I was looking for articles which describe the steps for Windows, as it will be easy for me to understand if I am missing something.

Comment: If you were following the first link - this one is for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. The following configuration must be set.

StrictModes no

It is by default set to yes, and is commented out in the sshd_config file. StrictModes is set to no for Public Key Authentication and Host Based Authentication.

None of the above articles (plus others too) have mentioned it, unfortunately.